# matplotlib colorbar extend in different color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I have data in a 2D matrix I want to plt.colorbar(extend = "both"), I have set my data to be maxed at 100 and mined at -100, now I want to see where my data is more than 100 (it's a saturated region) so the extent of the colorbar has to be in a different color than the colorbar is there a way to set a cmap with the tips in a different color? Like <"yellow"|"seismic"|"orange">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.set_over('orange')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_over) and [`.set_under('yellow')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) on the colormap.  If you're using a standard colormap, you should first make a copy to prevent that the original colormap gets changed.  [`.set_extremes(over=..., under=..., bad=...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_extremes) lets you change these colors in one go.  (`bad` is meant for invalid values, such as `np.nan` and `np.inf`; `bad` defaults to fully transparent).

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xmin, xmax = 0, 10
ymin, ymax = 0, 7

z = np.random.randint(-150, 150, size=(ymax, xmax))

cmap = plt.get_cmap('seismic').copy()
cmap.set_extremes(under='yellow', over='orange')
norm = plt.Normalize(-100, 100)
plt.imshow(z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar with set_over and set_under]

Seaborn's heatmap takes these colors into account when choosing either white or black for annotations.

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(z, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap=cmap, norm=norm, cbar_kws={'extend': 'both'})
```

[image: seaborn heatmap with over and under colors]